# How to receive data instantly with Architecture Compoenents?

Tags: android, architecture, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement the recommended architecture by Google and in a tutorial they show this diagram:

[image: Architecture Components design]

So I have a MainActivity and when the app starts it should go and fetch some data from the internet. I do those network operations in the Repository. Now my problem is that I don't know how to communicate properly between activities and Repository. For example MainActivity starts and immediately display a circular progress bar while Repository fetches the data. How can I stop the animation in MainActivity as soon as the data is inserted to the database? I guess I could call `observe()` on the `LiveData` and wait for `onChanged()`. Is there a better approach? What if there is no new data? Then `onChanged()` wouldn't be called...

Maybe I could send intent from Repository to MainActivity when there is no data so MainActivity knows it should stop the animation and if it doesn't receive the intent it just waits for `onChanged()`?

I guess I just don't feel confortable with the `onChanged()` method because I will never be sure of the operation it corresponds to. Maybe before the data from the network arrived there was some other data inserted which trigged `onChanged()` which would then stop the loading animation before it was supposed to.

Comment: Firstly, you don't mention `ViewModel` - are you using that? That is an important middleman. Secondly, are you using Room to store data, or only from the internet?

Comment: @Knossos Yes I'm using `ViewModel` and also `Room` to store the data in the database. The loading progress bar is a good example of my difficulties. I only want to stop that animation in MainActivity when the freshest data arrives. How do I implement that using this architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your issue in the comments, which I believe to answer your main question also.

You need to observe from your UI (Activity / Fragment) to a progress `LiveData` in your `ViewModel`. That could be working with a `Boolean` (`LiveData<Boolean>`). To represent the progress view being visible or not.

That in turn needs to take an identical `LiveData` from the Repository (declared in the Repository as a `MutableLiveData`). You then post updates to the progress `MutableLiveData` in the Repository.

Now, whenever the `MutableLiveData` receives a change, that exists in your `ViewModel` as it shares the variable reference, and it will pass to the observer in your UI.

-

Alternatively, you could return a `LiveData<Boolean>` from the method in your Repository that pulls data. That would then be observable in your UI.

Instead of Boolean, you could also use a more complicated structure containing more information. A message, error code, etc.